# php foreach loop doesn't gives all the results?

Tags: php, foreach, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to get specified words out of an string.

I do not know if I forgot something but it only prints the first two values? Can someone help me with that?

Thanks for the help!

```
$orgData["connector"] = 'some stringy thing SMA-female N-female FME-female';

if (preg_match_all('/(N-female|SMA-female|FME-female)/',$orgData["connector"], $matches)) {
    foreach ($matches as $i => $match) {
        if ($match[$i] == "N-female") {
            $con1 = "|Connector: N-female";
        }
        if ($match[$i] == "SMA-female") {
            $con2 = "|Connector: SMA-female";
        }
        if ($match[$i] == "FME-female") {
            $con3 = "|Connector: FME-female";
        }
        print_r($con1 . $con2 . $con3);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the output of $matches, when your print_r it?

Comment: `$match[$i]` should be just `$match`

Comment: when i print_r `$matches` all three words are in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a single variable and just append the matches once found:

```
$orgData = 'some stringy thing SMA-female N-female FME-female';
$con = "";
if (preg_match_all('/(?:N|SMA|FME)-female/', $orgData, $matches)) {
            foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {

                if ($match == "N-female") {
                    $con .= "|Connector: N-female";
                }
                if ($match == "SMA-female") {
                    $con .= "|Connector: SMA-female";
                }
                if ($match == "FME-female") {
                    $con .= "|Connector: FME-female";
                }
            }
        }
echo $con; // => |Connector: SMA-female|Connector: N-female|Connector: FME-female
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/KIGM6u).

Note I sharnk the pattern a bit: `(?:N|SMA|FME)-female` matches `N`, `SMA` or `FME` and then `-female`.